# Memory allocation issue in Haxe using Enum as Map key type

Tags: haxe, stage3d

I follow a 2D GPU library and saw an issue someone was having with memory allocation. An `Array<Map>` of enums is called every frame via `setBlendMode`, ultimately calling Haxe's `Type.enumParameters` each time.

```
class GBlendModeFunc
{
    private static var blendFactors:Array<Map<GBlendMode,Array<Context3DBlendFactor>>> = [
        [
            GBlendMode.NONE => [Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ZERO],
            GBlendMode.NORMAL => [Context3DBlendFactor.SOURCE_ALPHA, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
            GBlendMode.ADD => [Context3DBlendFactor.SOURCE_ALPHA, Context3DBlendFactor.DESTINATION_ALPHA],
            GBlendMode.MULTIPLY => [Context3DBlendFactor.DESTINATION_COLOR, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
            GBlendMode.SCREEN => [Context3DBlendFactor.SOURCE_ALPHA, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE],
            GBlendMode.ERASE => [Context3DBlendFactor.ZERO, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
        ],
        [
            GBlendMode.NONE => [Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ZERO],
            GBlendMode.NORMAL => [Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
            GBlendMode.ADD => [Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE],
            GBlendMode.MULTIPLY => [Context3DBlendFactor.DESTINATION_COLOR, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
            GBlendMode.SCREEN => [Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_COLOR],
            GBlendMode.ERASE => [Context3DBlendFactor.ZERO, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA],
        ]
    ];
    
    static public function setBlendMode(p_context:Context3D, p_mode:GBlendMode, p_premultiplied:Bool):Void {
        var p:Int = (p_premultiplied) ? 1 : 0;
        p_context.setBlendFactors(blendFactors[p][p_mode][0], blendFactors[p][p_mode][1]);
    }
}
```

The issue here is that `Type.enumParameters` creates a new Array each time it checks the values of enum array from `setBlendMode`, quickly adding tens of thousands of variables that trigger GC frequently.

I'm not familiar with best Haxe practices and not sure how to reorganize. Is there a more performant way to store the enums that won't create an allocation issue?

**Edit**: The [GBlendMode enums](https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D-ContextCommon/blob/26ebd5902c3a16506e92026f145e14a91ae4e13b/src/com/genome2d/context/GBlendMode.hx) cannot be converted to abstract enums because it breaks other functions.

**Edit 2:** A solution was proposed: https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D-ContextFlash/issues/17

Comment: Hope you don't mind I edited the title -- it's not the array of maps, but the map key type that causes the problem.

Comment: That's helpful. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see this looks like [Genome2D code](https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D-ContextFlash/blob/master/src/com/genome2d/context/GBlendModeFunc.hx).

But I don't see any code for the `GBlendMode` enum - and this whole thing hinges on that code. If `enum GBlendMode` is a normal enum, then at runtime they're arrays. The map getter function has to call `Type.enumParameters` to compare the keys -- I screen-shot a nodejs callstack to prove this to myself:

[image]

However, if `GBlendMode` is an *abstract* enum over `String`, like this:

```
enum abstract GBlendMode(String) {
  var NONE;
  var NORMAL;
  var ADD;
  var MULTIPLY;
  var SCREEN;
  var ERASE;
}
```

Then the keys are simple strings, and there is no enum comparison, and there are no intermediate arrays created.

Comment: It is Genome2D. Here is the original enum class: https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D-ContextCommon/blob/26ebd5902c3a16506e92026f145e14a91ae4e13b/src/com/genome2d/context/GBlendMode.hx

There was pull request that someone issued, but the author declined the pull because it wasn't prototypable: https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D-ContextCommon/pull/1

Would this cause the same issue or it it different because it's an abstract String?

Comment: Ah, this would probably cause the same issue... I'm not sure what `meta-programmed prototyping` is, so I'm not sure I can comment on how to avoid the problem.